# Facebook SDK for PHP 4.0.0 tutorials

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get started with the Facebook SDK for PHP 4.0.0 but all the tutorials that I can find are for previous versions. I'm having trouble understanding facebook's developer documentation so a tutorial to get started would help me. Can anybody suggest some resource for Facebook SDK for PHP 4.0.0 tutorials?

Answer (score 3):

Visit http://metah.ch/blog/2014/05/facebook-sdk-4-0-0-for-php-a-working-sample-to-get-started/
i find this tutorial . it's work

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a really minimal tutorial with a basic query here: https://www.apptic.me/blog/simple-facebook-php-sdk-4-tutorial.php

Answer (score 0):

I've written up a basic tutorial on how to get started with the [Facebook PHP SDK 4.0.0 here](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/). It gives a basic example of logging in and getting the user's data from the Graph API 2.0. Hopefully it's useful to you.